# Grunt + Postcss + autoprefixer not adding vendor prefixes

Tags: gruntjs, postcss, autoprefixer

Something is definitely wrong somewhere. My test file 'dist/css/prefixedpostcss-main.min.css' is well created but no vendor prefix are added :(
Thanks for advance,
spending lot of time on searching, reading… need the help of the community!

Here is below my Gruntfile.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


    /* grab the Bootstrap js and combine it with my custom scripts
    The goal is to limit the number of http requests to increase load time
     */
    // JS Concatenation Plugin 
    concat: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            banner: '',
        },
        scripts: {
            src: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js', 'js/plugins.js', 'js/main.js'],
            dest: 'dist/js/scripts.js',
        },
    },

    // JS Minification 
    uglify: {
        defer: {
            src: ['js/defer.js'], //input
            dest: 'dist/js/defer.min.js' //output
        },
        scripts: {
            src: ['dist/js/scripts.js'], //input
            dest: 'dist/js/scripts.min.js' //output
        },
    },


    // Sass to CSS
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'dist/css/main.css': 'sass/globals.scss' // this is our main scss file
            }
        },
        options: {
            compass: true,
            style: 'compressed',
            sourceMap: true
        }
    },

    // Post CSS (autoprefixer, mqpacker, cssnano) 
    postcss: {
        options: {
            map: true,
            // Load plugins 
            processors: [
                require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 1 version']}),// Runs Post CSS Autoprefixer 
                //require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            ]
        },
        dist: { 
        src: 'dist/css/main.css', 
        dest: 'dist/css/prefixedpostcss-main.min.css' 
        }
    },


    /* Auto Update the scripts and styles when working */
    watch: {
        grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },
        js: {
            files: ['js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
        },
        sass: {
            files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass', 'postcss'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
        },
        options: {
            livereload: false,
            spawn: false
        }
    },


    browserSync: {
      dev: {
         bsFiles: {
            src: [
              'sass/*.scss',
              'js/*.js',
              '*.html',
              'templates/*.html'
            ]
         },
    options: {
            watchTask: true,
            server: './'
         }
      }
    },


    htmlbuild: {
      dist: {
        src: 'src/index.html',
        dest: 'dist/',
        options: {
          beautify: true,
          relative: true,
          basePath: false,
      sections: {
            layout: {
              header: 'templates/header.html',
              footer: 'templates/footer.html'
            }
          },
        }
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'img/',
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'dist/img/build/'
             }]
        }
    },

    jshint: {
        files: {
          src: ['*.js', 'js/*.js']
        },
        options: {
            'curly': true,
            'eqeqeq': true,
            'eqnull': true,
            'immed': true,
            'noarg': true,
            'quotmark': 'single',
            'trailing': true,
            'undef': true,
            'unused': false,

            'node': true,
            'jquery': true,
            'browser': true,
            'devel': true,
        }
    },

});
// END GRUNT


// Load the plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-build');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');


// Default task(s).
//grunt.registerTask('dev', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
//grunt.registerTask('css', ['sass', 'postcss', 'autoprefixer', 'imagein']);
//grunt.registerTask('js', ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify']);
//grunt.registerTask('default', ['dev', 'css', 'js', 'notify']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'postcss:dist', 'concat', 'uglify', 'browserSync', 'watch']);
```

};

Here is below my package.json

```
{
  "name": "laurene",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-cssnano": "^2.1.0",
    "pixrem": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-browser-sync": "^2.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^3.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-cssnano": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-html-build": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-notify": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-spritesmith": "^6.6.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^2.5.2",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```